# nemo script for torrents

Tags: shell, bittorrent, nautilus

Hi I am new to scripting and I do mean a complete noobie. I am working on a script to automatically make a torrent with nemo scripts.

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR="$NEMO_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS"
BNAME=$(basename "$DIR")
TFILE="$BNAME.torrent"
TTRACKER="http://tracker.com/announce.php"
USER="USERNAME"
transmission-create -o "/home/$USER/Desktop/$TFILE" -t $TTRACKER "$DIR"
```

It does not work.

However if I replace

```
DIR="$NEMO_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS"
```

with

```
DIR="absolutepath"
```

than it works like a charm. It creates it on the desktop with the tracker I want. I think this would come in handy for many people. I dont really know what to put. Have questions please ask. Again complete noobie.

Comment: where is that `$NEMO....` variable being defined? As written above, it's completely undefined, which makes `$DIR` be an empty value. If it's coming from the nautilus shell, you should debug with and `env` call in that script, to see what variables ARE defined.

Comment: I am not sure exactly where DIR is defined. I think it is defined in nemo. It got it from another script that came preinstalled in nemo actions.What do you mean "env"? Again complete noobie. Sorry for the ignorance.

Comment: change first line to `#!/bin/bash -vx`. This turn on debugging/trace mode, you will see each line before it is executed, as code, then the evaluated line, with variables replaced with values. As @MarcB says, its likely that you'll see that there is no value in $DIR. Then you have to figure out why `$NEMO_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS` is empty. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The $NEMO_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS is the same as $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS.  It's populated by nemo/nautilus when you run the script and contains a newline-delimited (I think) list of the selected files/folders.  Assuming you are selecting only one file or folder, I don't really see why it wouldn't work - unless the newline character is in there and causing problems.  If that's the case, you may be able to strip it with sed.  Not running nemo or nautilus, so I can't test it.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution to yours and my problem [https://askubuntu.com/questions/243105/nautilus-scripts-nautilus-script-selected-file-paths-have-problems-with-spac][1]

The variable $NEMO_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATH/$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATH is a list of paths/filenames seperated by a Newline. This messes up anything that assumes its just one filename, even if it is.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$NEMO_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS" | while read DIR; do
    BNAME=$(basename "$DIR")
    TFILE="$BNAME.torrent"
    TTRACKER="http://tracker.com/announce.php"
    USER="USERNAME"
    transmission-create -o "/home/$USER/Desktop/$TFILE" -t $TTRACKER "$DIR"
done
```

Notice it seems to do an extra pass for the newline. You either need to filter that out or put an if the file/folder exists